NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected repsonse code 200 in Android Studio using volley
I want to display a feed of posts with images on my app that I get from an HTTP call to my backend. What I return from my backend is a json-list of posts with their images encoded in base64. When I return more posts it's more likely to run into the NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 200 for http://10.0.2.2:5000/feed/get error. In my backend logs, I always get a 200 response, and also looking in android studio's Network Inspector it's still 200.
I read here that it might be a problem with the emulator and to try with a real device instead. However I don't have an android device to try it on.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Snippet of my project that sends the request
public class APICalls {
    private final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000/";
    private final Context context;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public APICalls(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        // Create one queue that holds all requests
        this.queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    }

    public void sendRequest(int method, @Nullable JSONObject jsonObject,
                            @Nullable String token, String route, APIListener listener) {

        // Create string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(method, url+route,
                response -> {
                    Log.v("NETWORK", "");
                    // Create APIObject based on response data using GSON
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    APIObject apiObject = gson.fromJson(response, APIObject.class);

                    // Call listeners function
                    listener.onSuccess(apiObject);
                },
                volleyError -> {

                    // This if clause will determine if the error we caught was an error from
                    // our backend or some other error thrown by volley
                    if (volleyError instanceof ClientError) {
                        // If we get in here, it means it's an error on our backend
                        // Get byte array from response data
                        byte[] byteArray = volleyError.networkResponse.data;

                        // Convert byte array to APIObject using GSON
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String jsonStringFromByteArray = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        APIObject errorResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonStringFromByteArray, APIObject.class);

                        // Call listeners function
                        listener.onError(errorResponse);
                    } else {
                        // If we get in here, it means the error was thrown for something else.
                        Log.e("NETWORK", "Network error.");
                        volleyError.printStackTrace();

                        APIObject errorResponse = new APIObject("fail", "Network error. Please try again.");
                        listener.onError(errorResponse);

                    }
                }) {
                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() {
                    return jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json";
                }
            };
        // Set maxNumRetries to 100 for debugging purposes
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 100, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

}

The stacktrace:
[77] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 200 for http://10.0.2.2:5000/feed/get
Network error.
com.android.volley.NetworkError
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:203)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
Could not get data: Network error. Please try again.

I tried to show a list of posts in a RecyclerView in Android Studio, but I received a NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 200 for http://10.0.2.2:5000/feed/get  error instead.
